# Set Theory - converting description into theoretic mathematical representation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on converting these descriptions into set theoretic mathematical form but I am struggling with these two:

• Let U be the set of all possible sets. S4: The set of all sets that
contain themelves.

• Let U be the set of all possible sets. S5: The set of all sets that don’t
contain themselves.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $S_4 = \{ x \in U \mid x \in x \}$.

Comment: Now can you write $S_5$ ?

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do S5

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but would S5 = {  ∈  ∣  ∉  }

Comment: I get nervous whenever someone talks about "*the set of all possible sets*" but given the context clues, I imagine that the sequence of exercises are about to point out the fact or have you reach the conclusion that $S_5$ both must and must not be an element of itself simultaneously, a result known as [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).  The usual way that we get over this is by allowing for the existence of things "bigger" or "weirder" than sets, of which $U$ and $S_5$ would be examples of called [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)).

Comment: B contains A means A subset B.

Comment: @WilliamElliot What?  No, that is not the intended interpretation here at all.  Very clearly we are talking about containment as in the context of containing as an element.  It is entirely possible for one set to contain another set (E.g. powersets have sets as elements).  Now... a set containing itself is inconsistent with the axioms of ZF set theory, but exploring why it is inconsistent and what might happen without that axiom is an important step in building a foundation.

Comment: If "an element of" was intended, then that is what needs to be said. @MauroALLEGRANZA